# How can I use multiple values from core data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

```
@FetchRequest(entity: NoneExistingSubscription.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \NoneExistingSubscription.name, ascending: true)]) var names: FetchedResults<NoneExistingSubscription>
@FetchRequest(entity: NoneExistingSubscription.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \NoneExistingSubscription.price, ascending: true)]) var prices: FetchedResults<NoneExistingSubscription>

ScrollView{
ForEach(self.names, id: \.self) { test in
    MySubscribe(price: 15, title: test.name ?? "Unknown", subTitle: "Family Plan", logo: "Netflix_Symbol")
    }
}
```

Core Data call currently only title: test.name, but I want to call one more value for the price here.

I saw some replies for those asks and it seemed that I should use ForEach one more time in ForEach, but it doesn't work just.

```
ForEach(self.names, id: \.self) { test in
MySubscribe(price: 15, title: test.name ?? "Unknown", subTitle: "Family Plan", logo: "Netflix_Symbol")
    }
}

ForEach(self.prices, id: \.self) { test in
MySubscribe(price: 15, title: test.name ?? "Unknown", subTitle: "Family Plan", logo: "Netflix_Symbol")
    }
}
```

Just like this call only one value works fine.
And I want use two values at the same time in MySubscribe().

Can someone help me for this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test the code but you don't need 2 `@FetchRequest`

```
@FetchRequest(entity: NoneExistingSubscription.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \NoneExistingSubscription.name, ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \NoneExistingSubscription.price, ascending: true)]) var items: FetchedResults<NoneExistingSubscription>

ScrollView{
ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in
    MySubscribe(price: item.price, title: ("\(item.name ?? "Unknown") \(item.price)"), subTitle: "Family Plan", logo: "Netflix_Symbol")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!
With your code, it works, but it calls only item.price, or item.name.

I don't know why it doesn't show me the results of them(item.price and item.name at the same time).
Why just only one of them!?
But it helps me already a lot! Thank you so much again!

Comment: What do you mean you want to see them together? Try `("\(item.name ?? "Unknown") \(item.price)")` that should give you a `String`. If I answered your question please accept the answer above

Comment: With your code, if I use only item.name or item.price, it works great, but if I use item.name and item.price at the same time just like your original code, it shows me only the results of item.name.  But I will try it again with String which you mentioned just now!

Comment: In my code, there was a problem, but now it has solved, and works everything fine. 
Thank you soooo much again for your help!!!